# How to call the whole function under 'with' statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, with-statement, syntactic-sugar

I have the following sample function:

```
def Run(self):
    with self._resource() as r:
        # a lot of code uses |r|
        pass
    # end of 'with' statement
# end of function body
```

I don't want to lose the visual space of the whole function body because of additional indent inside `with` statement.

Also I don't want to call the `_resource()` outside the class scope - it breaks encapsulation in some ways, i.e. this is not a good way:

```
with obj._resource() as r:
    obj.Run(r)
```

Is there any pretty way to run the same code without losing visual space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only this function to deal with, it's pretty simple:

```
class Foo(object):
    def Run(self):
        with self._resource() as r:
            return self._RunWithResource(r)

    def _RunWithResource(self, r):
        # ...
```

If you want to repeat the pattern, a decorator might help.  More or less:

```
from functools import wraps
def with_resource(f):
    @wraps
    def wrapper(self, *a, **kw):
        with self._resource() as r:
            return f(self, r, *a, **kw)
    return wrapper

class Foo(object):
    @with_resource
    def Run(self, r):
        # ...
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps